# Translate pseudocode to python?

Tags: python, syntax, translate

I need some help translating this [pseudocode](http://www.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=30ur9s5&s=5#.UoLMNKzYW2a) to python,
I made some questions in the code, would really enjoy some help :)
The idea behind the code I do understand, a divide and conquer technique to binary multiplication.

[image]

How would you guys have written this in python?

```
def mult(A,B):

        n = len(A)
        if (n <= 1):
            return (A[0]*B[0])

        p = A[0:n/2]
        q = A[n/2:n]
        r = B[0:n/2]
        s = B[n/2:n]

        pr = mult(p,r)
        ps = mult(p,s)
        rq = mult(r,q)
        qs = mult(q,s)

        sum = ps + rq # no problem adding like this I guess
```

?

Okay, I don't know what this "in" does in the pseudocode aswell as "end".
    and the shift I suppose it's just to use the "<<" operator. Or maybe not in this case because it's a list, but it's simple to make a help function for that.

Comment: how do u expect us to translate this pseudocode, when there is no pseudocode to begin with? Also I have no idea what your code is doing, you need to add comments

Comment: There is a link in the first sentence to the pseudocode.
And it does a recursive binary multiplication! (My code is not complete) - check the link.

Comment: Where did you find this pseudocode?  Also, what does the "`par`" function used in it do?

Comment: I found it here http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15210-s12/www/lectures/lecture02.pdf#5 at the end of page 5.

Comment: Why did you translate `|A| ≤ 1` to `n == 1` instead of `<=`?

Comment: Now that I look at the link, this is a "first attempt", which is then analyzed to show its badness and then further improved. So… why do you want to port a bad recursive multiplication algorithm to Python in the first place?

Comment: I am supposed to analyze a "bad" algorithm at first, then motivate stuff you can improve and give a new better time complexity according to the better algorithm.

Comment: @Depenz: So this is part of a class you're taking? Did the teacher really assign you this code without telling you what language it's in, leaving you to guess what functions like `par` and `shift` and language constructs like `let` do?

Comment: @abarnert This code I found on the web. I needed a divide and conquer algoritm for binary multiplication. And the idea behind this example i understand, thats why i needed help translating it from as you say ML to python. The shift must be equal to pythons << operator or else i am confused.

Comment: @Depenz: If `A` and `B` are lists—which they clearly are, because you're indexing them—then how could `shift` be equal to `<<`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I don't think this is pseudocode at all, but rather code in a real language, probably one derived from (S)ML. If you knew what language it was it, it would be a lot easier to interpret it—instead of trying to guess what things like `shift` mean, you could look it up in the docs for that language.

---

That being said, there are a number of things you've clearly translated wrong.

---

First, you turned this:

```
if |A| ≤ 1
```

… into this:

```
n = len(A)
if (n == 1):
```

Besides adding in meaningless extra parentheses, you've broken the recursive base case of A being *empty*.

---

Next, `par` may just mean something like "you can do these in parallel if you want", so it may be OK to ignore it. On the other hand, given that you're taking this from lecture notes for a class in parallel algorithms and data structures, that thing you ignored may be the whole *point*. Obviously, in Python, you'd need to map it to something different—e.g., create a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, submit the four recursive calls, then wait for all four futures? (Although it's possible this is meant to be a late-as-possible-binding language, in which case you don't want to wait for the futures here, but rather change each expression that uses one of these values so that it waits on the future it needs, and submit those expressions to the executor as well.)

---

Anyway, you've translated the recursive calls to the function being defined into calls to some different function. All of these:

```
    pr = binary_mult(p,r)
    ps = binary_mult(p,s)
    rq = binary_mult(r,q)
    qs = binary_mult(q,s)
```

… need to be calling `mult`.

---

The `let … in … end` is effectively a way of saying that the first … is a bunch of local variables for the second …. You *could* translate that by, e.g., replacing the `end` with a `del` on each variable, but I think it's fine to ignore that as you have.

But you've left off the most important part, this bit:

```
shift(pr, n) + shift(sum, n/2) + qs
```

I'm not sure that last `+` is a `+`. It may be a different symbol, or a screenshot taken while a cursor was moving over a `+`, or a scan of a printout with a speck of dust on the `+`, or some other great example of why you should post text instead of pictures of text when you want help with the code in that text…

Anyway, you need to do whatever that is doing (and return the result). That's the key piece of the function; all the `let … in` stuff is just setup for this expression.

---

Going with your guesses as to what the functions mean, and my guesses as to the almost-SML syntax, ignoring the parallel bit, something like what you wrote is close to a direct translation:

```
def shift(A, n):
    # Taking a wild guess
    return A + [0 for _ in range(n)]

def mult(A, B):
    n = len(A)
    if n <= 1:
        return [A[0] * B[0]]
    else:
        p, q = A[:n//2], A[n//2:]
        r, s = B[:n//2], B[n//2:]
        pr, ps, rq, qs = mult(p, r), mult(p, s), mult(r, q), mult(q, s)
        sum = ps + rq
        return pr << n + sum << n//2 + qs
```

I'm willing to bet we've guessed at least one thing wrong. For example, maybe `+` is supposed to be element-wise addition rather than list concatenation. The only way to find out is to run it with some numbers and check the output. The only thing is, I don't even know what the *inputs* are supposed to be. Maybe big-endian place-value lists of binary digits? In that case, `+` has to be element addition *with carry*.

In fact, it's possible that these things are supposed to be usable simultaneously as numbers and as big-endian lists of bits. No built-in Python type works that way, but it's not too hard to build one… or to find one on PyPI. `bitarray` and `bitstring` look like plausible candidates.

Comment: Yes, mistake about forgetting the first base case, my bad!
binary_mult was a typo sorry!

There is a link to the code, am pretty sure it's a "+" sign.

Edit: There is no parallel programming in this course. That link i just found while googling around. The point is to make a binary multiplication, and I wanted to implement the algorithm I found to python, thats ok. The hardest part is the algorithm analys I beleive. But thats another problem.
And yes i left out the shift part since i did not know where to write it! Thx

Comment: What would your python code be to this binary multiplication (without paralell programming) ?

Comment: @Depenz: I suppose I'd start with as direct a translation as possible. Let me edit the answer.